# Flowplayer Video source error

Tags: php, html, flowplayer

I have a PHP script that helps me display a video with Flowplayer.

```
$filepath =  str_replace('/','\\', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. VIDEO_PATH . $video->video_path_original_quality);
```

gives me filepath as

C:\wamp\www\XYZ\admin\uploads\videos\video-800-old_original.mp4

where VIDEO_PATH = XYZ\admin\uploads\videos.

My problem is that the video source in my HTML still shows a blank value. The code I have written is

```
<video>
          <source type="video/mp4" src="<?php str_replace('/','\\',$filepath);?>"/>
```

Can anybody let me know what's wrong ? I have tried 'echo' as well, but it doesn't help either. I am working on Codeigniter

Comment: The path needs tobe `/XYZ/admin/uploads/videos/video-800-old_original.mp4`

Comment: Can you shed some light on it ?

Comment: The path needs tobe a **relative path** E.G: not include `C:\wamp\www` part of the path. The first `/` will bring the path to the root.

Comment: Thanks man! I used the base_url() in PHP and edited the VIDEO_PATH variable as I am invoking the video from another admin folder.

So now my path looks like 
http://localhost/XYZ/admin/uploads/videos/video-800-old_original.mp4

Answer (score 0):

You don't echo anything:

```
<?php str_replace…
```

should be:

```
<?php echo str_replace…
```

or, more typically:

```
<?= str_replace…
```

Comment: Hey Rich, I did try echo. However, I believe the problem was in the url formation. Replaced $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] with base_url() and modified the path of the variable VIDEO_PATH, and it worked, ofcourse with an echo.